# Mockery - partial mocks

Tags: php, unit-testing, mockery

I've got a problem with understanding what **partial mocks** are used for. A very simple example below:

UserEventTest.php

```
class UserEventTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function tearDown()
    {
        Mockery::close();
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function user_register()
    {   
        $mailer = Mockery::mock('\App\Mailer');
        $mailer->shouldReceive('setEmail')
               ->shouldReceive('sendActivationMessage')
               ->andReturn(true);

        $user = Mockery::mock(\App\User::class);
        $user->shouldReceive('getEmail')
             ->andReturn('test@test.com');     

        $userEventHandler = new \App\UserEventHandler($mailer, $user);

        $this->assertEquals(true, $userEventHandler->onUserRegister());
    }

}
```

This test passes and doesn't actually send an email (so it's fine). When I change this mock to a partial mock, like this:

```
$mailer = Mockery::mock('\App\Mailer')->makePartial();
```

It passes as well, but I'm wondering why and what's the difference?

And for example, changing it into:

```
$mailer = Mockery::mock('\App\Mailer[setEmail]');
```

Sends actually an email.

Could anyone explain me these differences (**especially comparing partial mocks to normal standard mocks**) and when to use a particular type of mock.

Comment: Uncle Bob has done a great job of explaining the difference between all the possible test doubles: https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2014/05/14/TheLittleMocker.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class ClassYouWantToTest {

  public function a();

  public function b();

}
```

If your method a() use method b() and you want to mock b() to test a() only, then you have to use partial mock for your class.

To resume, you use partial mock **only for the class you want to test**, if you have to mock one of their methods.

Comment: So it's used only within a **class scope** (between class methods)? I never need it for testing between different classes?

Comment: Yes, within a class scope (actually the class you want to test, otherwise you use usual mock).
In fact you don't need between classes. In that case use normal mocks.